# Are there any major issues using inbuilt SOAP support in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I've seen some questions where people have trouble with accessing .NET SOAP web services from PHP and there appears to be an issue with namespaces when using a distributed WSDL.

Are there any other problems with the inbuilt SOAP support in PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience the interoperability of the built in soap classes is the best I've seen so far with PHP soap libraries.  The main issue is usually understanding what the WSDL is asking for in terms of types.  Using a combination of __getMethods() and __getTypes() you should be able to figure out how to construct the objects (or arrays) to pass to the remote methods with little effort.  I've used the SoapClient to connect to at least .NET and WebSphere and many others with little issue.